# Division by an interval

Tags: arithmetic, intervals

I have a function:

```
f[x_] := 1792 - 256 x - 2240 x^2 + 320 x^3 + 448 x^4 - 64 x^5 - 6 x^6 + 6 x^7
```

interval:

```
inter = Interval[{-4, 3}]
```

x:

```
x = Mean@First@(List @@ inter) // N
```

and formula:

```
IntervalIntersection[inter, x - (f[x]/((1/4) f'[x] + (3/4) f'[x + (2/3) (inter - x)]))]
```

The formula doesn't calculates correctly because of division `f[x]` by interval `((1/4) f'[x] + (3/4) f'[x + (2/3) (inter - x)])`

Though explicitly it can be done by hand, as **`f[x] == 1349.86`** and **`((1/4) f'[x] + (3/4) f'[x + (2/3) (inter - x)]) == Interval[{-52452.4, 45111.9}]`**.

So I suppose it `f[x]/((1/4) f'[x] + (3/4) f'[x + (2/3) (inter - x)])` should be eq to `Interval[{-0.0257349, 0.0299225}]`  but the result is `Interval[{-\[Infinity], -0.0257349}, {0.0299225, \[Infinity]}]`

***Can you help me to resolve it ?***[image]

Comment: It seems the issue is that  your definition of a reciprocal of an interval is different from the one mathematica uses. What would you expect for `1/Interval[{-1, 1}]` ?

Comment: One should keep in mind that every time `Interval` is evaluated with machine precision arguments, the interval is expanded by roughly machine error.  This makes an epsilon difference, either literally `$MachineEpsilon` or in the case of `0.`, `$MinMachineNumber`.  Not usually important unless you write code that assumes they are unchanged (or your problem is ill-conditioned).

Answer (score 1):

f[x]/((1/4) f'[x] + (3/4) f'[x + (2/3) (inter - x)]) equals to Interval[{-[Infinity], -0.0257349}, {0.0299225, [Infinity]}]. Please check the geometric representation of it.

In:

```
Clear[f, x, a, b, inter]
f[x_] := 1792 - 256 x - 2240 x^2 + 320 x^3 + 448 x^4 - 64 x^5 - 
   6 x^6 + 6 x^7;
inter = Interval[{-4, 3}];
x = Mean@First@(List @@ inter) // N;
IntervalIntersection[inter, 
  x - (f[x]/((1/4) f'[x] + (3/4) f'[x + (2/3) (inter - x)]))];
f[x]/((1/4) f'[x] + (3/4) f'[x + (2/3) (inter - x)]);

a = f[x] (*1349.859375`*)
b = ((1/4) f'[x] + (3/4) f'[
     x + (2/3) (inter - 
         x)]) (*Interval[{-52452.38917824089`,45111.86612654332`}]*)

a/b (*Interval[{-\[Infinity],-0.025734945464790555`},{0.\
029922490264834276`,\[Infinity]}]*)

(*geometric representation of a/b*)   
Plot[a/x1, {x1, -52452.38917824089`, 45111.86612654332`}, 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

Out:

```
1349.86
Interval[{-52452.4, 45111.9}]
Interval[{-\[Infinity], -0.0257349}, {0.0299225, \[Infinity]}]
```

[image]

Comment: ok, how can I divide `Interval[{-\[Infinity], -0.0257349}, {0.0299225, \[Infinity]}]` into two `Interval[{-\[Infinity], -0.0257349}]` and `Interval[{0.0299225, \[Infinity]}]` ?

Comment: Interval[{-\[Infinity], -0.0257349}, {0.0299225, \[Infinity]}] is a 2D interval. Interval[{-\[Infinity], -0.0257349}] is 1D interval. I am not sure it's feasible.

Comment: you can do this: `Interval /@ List @@ Interval[{-\[Infinity], -0.0257349}, {0.0299225, \[Infinity]}]`